# MVC 4 SPA without JS frameworks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I spent almost an entire day researching possibilities for using SPA with MVC 4. I came upon template after template and JS framework after framework. People are using Knockout, Backbone.js, Breeze.js, and so many other frameworks. It also seems like a lot of people are using MVVM to display data.

But what I was really looking for was if there is a way to develop an SPA that does **not** depend on multiple JS frameworks to make it work. Is there some minimal setup that uses the bare minimum of plugins and frameworks to get an SPA working? I noticed we could use just History.js, but then we would need some sort of routing abstraction, correct? So what if we just want to setup simplistic routing (browser history management) and not MVVM? Are there options for doing that?

(please let me know if I can phrase my question better or if I can improve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure sammy.js or history.js on page load and load views dynamically...

```
 sammy.get('#/(.*)', function (context) {
      var url = this.params['splat'];
      $("#main").load(url);
 });
```

for example if we load localhost:333/Home/ContactUs... It will read the contact us view and load contents dynamically.

Here are other libraries which you can compare if you want to choose a js framework for SPA.  I think angular covers all requirement for spa as single library.
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the response! Now one other thing I've been confused about, related to MVC 4. So I understand being able to click on a link on a page to dynamically load a view (it shows localhost:333/Home/ContactUs in the URL, but loads the view via AJAX). But what about setting up MVC 4, so when someone browses to localhost:333/Home/ContactUs directly, it doesn't go to just that PartialView? How do you get MVC 4 and sammy.js or history.js to work together seamlessly?

Comment: You have to configure sammy or history.js... I am using sammy.js its pretty good and when you will configure it many things will be clear for you.  When someone open it directly then definitely it will open partial view but you can check in controller whether its ajax request or not... Sammy.js works with hash base url you can define different routes and perform actions